# How to find the infinite sum $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(4m+1)^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

I know that $$\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2m+1)^n}=(1-2^{-n})\zeta(n),$$ where $\zeta(n)$ is the Riemann zeta value. But how to find the infinite sum $$\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(4m+1)^n},$$ where $n$ is an integer with $n\geq 2$. I have tried that
$$\sum\frac{1}{(4m+1)^n}+\sum\frac{1}{(4m+2)^n}+\sum\frac{1}{(4m+3)^n}+\sum\frac{1}{(4m+4)^n}=\zeta(n),$$
and $$\sum\frac{1}{(4m+2)^n}=2^{-n}(1-2^{-n})\zeta(n),$$
$$\sum\frac{1}{(4m+4)^n}=4^{-n}\zeta(n).$$ But the two left sums can not be well represented.

Comment: What did you try? Using the same steps as are done in calculating the sum you cite should work for your expression.

Comment: I have added my attempt but I am still confused.@5xum

Answer (score 2):

I think that the simplest is to use the Hurwitz zeta function
$$\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(a\,m+b)^n}=a^{-n} \zeta \left(n,\frac{b}{a}\right)$$and
$$a^{-n} \zeta \left(n,\frac{a}{a}\right)=a^{-n} \zeta(n)$$

Answer (score 1):

For $n\ge 2$ integer there is no closed-form for $$\sum_{m= 0}^\infty (4m+1)^{-n}$$ There is one only for $$\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty (4m+1)^{-n}$$
Similarly there is a closed-form for $\zeta(2n)$ and $\sum_{m=-\infty, m\ne 0}^\infty m^{-2n+1} = 0$ but there isn't a closed-form for $\zeta(2n+1)$.

Comment: Is there no closed form, or no _known_ closed form? AFAIK the corresponding question for $\zeta(3)$ is still open, and the only claim I can find to even have shown that $\zeta(3)/\pi^3$ is irrational is from someone on arXiv who claims to have also solved several other open problems regarding the irrationality measure of $\pi$.

Comment: For odd $n\geq 3$, there is a closed form in zeta values and Euler numbers though: $$
\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(4m + 1)^n }}}  = \frac{1}{2}\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{2^n }}} \right)\zeta (n) + \frac{1}{4}\left( {\frac{\pi }{2}} \right)^n \frac{{\left| {E_{n - 1} } \right|}}{{(n - 1)!}}.
$$ If I understand correctly, the OP is happy with an expression involving (odd) zeta values.

Answer (score 1):

Maple does the case $n=2$ in terms of [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant) $G$.
$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(4m+1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{16}+\frac{G}{2}
$$
But of course there is no known simple evaluaton of Catalan's constant.

Maple does all other cases in terms of the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) $\psi(x) = \Gamma'(x)/\Gamma(x)$.

$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(4m+1)^n} = 
\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n(n-1)!}\;\psi^{(n-1)}\left(\frac14\right)
$$
Here $\psi^{(n-1)}$ is the derivative of order $n-1$.  These derivatives of the digamma function are also called [polygamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function).

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition of the polygamma function:

$$\psi^{(n-1)}(a)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}(n-1)!}{(m+a)^{n}}$$

we have

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(4m+1)^{n}}=\frac1{4^{n}}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(m+1/4)^{n}}=\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n(n-1)!}\psi^{(n-1)}\left(\frac14\right).$$

There is a closed form for $\psi^{(2n)}\left(\frac14\right)$:

$$\psi^{(2n)}\left(\frac14\right)=(2^{2n}-2^{1+4n})(2n)!\zeta(2n+1)-2^{2n-1}|E_{2n}|\pi^{2n+1},$$

where $E_n$ is the [Euler numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_numbers).

Examples:

\begin{align}
\psi^{(2)}\left(\frac14\right)&=-56\zeta(3)-2\pi^3;\\
\psi^{(4)}\left(\frac14\right)&=-11904\zeta(5)-40\pi^5;\\
\psi^{(6)}\left(\frac14\right)&=-5852160\zeta(7)-1952\pi^7;\\
\psi^{(8)}\left(\frac14\right)&=-5274501120\zeta(9)-177280\pi^9;\\
\psi^{(10)}\left(\frac14\right)&=-7606429286400\zeta(11)-25866752\pi^{11}.
\end{align}

---

Proof: Start with the definition of the Drichlet beta function

\begin{gather*}
\beta(a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^{a}}\\
\left\{\text{use $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^na_{n}=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}$}\right\}\\
=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(4n+1)^{a}}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{a}}.
\end{gather*}
Evaluation of the first sum:
\begin{gather}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(4n+1)^{a}}=\frac1{4^{a}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1/4)^{a}}\\
\{\text{make use of the definition of the polygamma function}\}\\
=\frac{(-1)^{a}2^{-2a}}{(a-1)!}\psi^{(a-1)}\left(\frac14\right).
\end{gather}
Evaluation of the second sum: Set $a_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)^{a}}$ in $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^na_{n}=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}$,
\begin{gather*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{a}}=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^{a}}+\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{a}}\\
\{\text{shift the index $n$ by $-1$ in both series on the RHS}\}\\
=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{a}}+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{a}}\\
=\frac12\zeta(a)+\frac12\eta(a)\\
\{\text{substitute $\eta(a)=(1-2^{1-a})\zeta(a)$}\}\\
=(1-2^{-a})\zeta(a).
\end{gather*}

Combine the two sums, we get

$$\beta(a)=\frac{(-1)^{a}2^{1-2a}}{(a-1)!}\psi^{(a-1)}\left(\frac14\right)-(1-2^{-a})\zeta(a)$$

or

$$\beta(2a+1)=-\frac{2^{-1-4a}}{(2a)!}\psi^{(2a)}\left(\frac14\right)-(1-2^{-1-2a})\zeta(2a+1)\tag{a}.$$

---

On the other hand, start with the integral form of the Dirichlet beta function,
\begin{gather*}
\beta(2a+1)=\frac{1}{(2a)!}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{(2a)!}\left(\int_0^\infty-\int_1^\infty\right)\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x\\
=\frac{1}{(2a)!}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x-\frac{1}{(2a)!}\underbrace{\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x}_{x\to 1/x}\\
=\frac{1}{(2a)!}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x-\frac{1}{(2a)!}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x\\
\left\{\text{add  $\beta(2a+1):=\frac{1}{(2a)!}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x$ to both sides then divide by $2$}\right\}\\
=\frac{1}{2(2a)!}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x\\
=\frac{|E_{2a}|}{2(2a)!}\left(\frac{\pi}2{}\right)^{2a+1}\tag{b}, 
\end{gather*}

where $E_r$ is the [Euler numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_numbers).

Combine $(a)$ and $(b)$,

$$\psi^{(2a)}\left(\frac14\right)=(2^{2a}-2^{1+4a})(2a)!\zeta(2a+1)-2^{2a-1}|E_{2a}|\pi^{2a+1}.$$

Comment: If there are any reference or website show the details of $\psi^{(2n)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$? Thank you!

Comment: @lynn_sky the proof in my book but i will add it in the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much!@ Ali Shadhar

Comment: @lynn_sky you welcome :)